# Visual Studio 2010 Adds {oj to query DB/2

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, db2

I am using vs 2010 to run/design queries for DB/2. I am trying to do a left outer join and for some reason VS will add {oj to the query like so:

1)

```
SELECT DEPTNO,DEPTNAME,EMPNO,LASTNAME,WORKDEPT
FROM   DEPT LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP
ON     DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.WORKDEPT
```

2)

```
SELECT DEPTNO,DEPTNAME,EMPNO,LASTNAME,WORKDEPT
FROM   {oj DEPT LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP
ON     DEPT.DEPTNO = EMP.WORKDEPT}
```

Then it complains about the {

How to I stop this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar issue with visual studio 2008. You have to edit the query as text.

If you have already created a dataset, right click on it in the list of datasets then pick query from the menu. Then in the query designer that appears the button is in top left.

If it a new data set you can keep query type as text and just type the query in the query box.

Using the edit as text method means your you can't you the in-build graphical query designer as this will revert the query to use the "oj" syntax.

This explain using the query designer in text form
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms345246.aspx#Textbased